# Displaying same image to many monitors (10+)?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, splitter

I have a WD TV Media Player, which streams content from the Internet onto my TV. I am using monitors instead, with a HDMI cable, and I need to display the same image to about 8-15 monitors (still figuring this number out).

It seems to me that all I need is a HDMI splitter, but I am skeptical something like that could work for so many monitors. Would it be able to work with a little streamer Media Player?

Thanks.

Comment: The load of handling outputs to 10+ monitors isn't of the Media Player but of the HDMI splitter. I recommend getting a really good HDMI splitter (which is able to handle such load) with the suitable amount of HDMI ports.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use a HDMI splitter. You would want to find one that is powered so it amplifies the signal. Kind of like [this](http://www.startech.com/AV/Splitters/HDMI-Splitters/8-port-hdmi-splitter-and-amplifier~ST128HDMI2) one. I actually use this one for this exact thing.

One thing you need to look at though this is distance. How far away are your target displays? HDMI is spec'd for 25 feet. I have ran 50 feet for HDMI without issue, but going through a splitter can degrade the signal. If you are looking at long distances, then you will want to look at things like HDMI over IP or using an analog video source.